# How to alert when a new SQL Agent Job is created in SQL Server 2019?

Tags: sql-server-2019, sql-server-agent, jobs

How do you alert when a new SQL Agent Job is created in SQL Server 2019?  Is there some kind of trigger that would work here?

Comment: If you are trying to get alert when a rogue sysadmin creates a job, the rogue sysadmin could obviously disable the trigger...